# How do I get a draggable to revert to the original position only if it was dragged onto an invalid droppable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an element I want to allow to be dragged anywhere. However, if it is dropped onto a droppable which refuses it (via accept) I want it to revert to the original position before the drag. How can I accomplish this?

EDIT: to be more specific: I want two conditions to be met in order for the item to be moved back: 1. It was dropped on a droppable and 2. The droppable didnt accept said item. Draggable's revert option only checks condition 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have some code which I think should work. Note that it doesn't use the `accept` option to specify which draggables the droppables will accept. Instead, you'll have to check whether or not a draggable should be rejected manually, in the drop event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.droppable-class').droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            // check whether or not draggable should be rejected here...
            if (...) {
                ui.draggable.data('rejected', true);
            }
        }
    });

    $('.draggable-class').draggable({
        revert: false,
        start: function(event, ui) {
            ui.helper.data('rejected', false);
            ui.helper.data('original-position', ui.helper.offset());
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.helper.data('rejected') === true) {
                ui.helper.offset(ui.helper.data('original-position'));
            }
        }
     });
```

Comment: Is there a way to fade in the draggable in it's original place? I've tried to change the display: none/block; setting but then it changes the flow of the other elements. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use sortable dude - something like:

```
    $('#sortable-area').sortable({
    accept: '.child',
    items: '.child',
    revert: 300,
    opacity: 0.8,
    containment: 'document'
});
```

This should automatically snap the element back if it isn't far enough to replace one of the other elements. You just put this on the container

Comment: To point out - you may get away with draggable, the 'revert' option above is the one to set the speed at which the element will return if it hasn't met its droppable parent

Comment: The problem is that I want to allow the item to be moved to empty space which sortable doesnt allow

Comment: That's fine - try using draggable but giving it the revert option as I mentioned in my previous comment, there may even be a true/false option for it.

Comment: I want two conditions to be met in order for the item to be moved back: 1. It was dropped on a droppable and 2. The droppable didnt accept said item. Revert only checks condition 2.